# Understanding the structure of a Monero transaction

Tags: testnet, transaction-data

So I am trying to understand how Monero works under the hood, and I was looking at the transaction below. (If you would like to see it in your own daemon, switch to testnet and just type `print_tx 3cf34714d411d051722ec32990bf46567c7ae3432871f75f58005cb6b5b3021e`) I would like to know what some of these fields mean. (I know that what follows might be seen as many questions, but you can view them as optional sub-questions to the main question: **How is a Monero transaction structured?**) Any insight on any of these parts, or how they are related would be greatly appreciated. For example:

1) What are the numbers inside "key_offsets"? The size of that vector seems to change according to the mixin chosen, so I assume that those numbers are a way to refer to the outputs involved in the ring signature, but what is it? I mean, clearly they aren't transaction ids,and it doesn't seem like they are block heights either.

2) What is the field "extra"?

3) Inside "rct_signatures", it says "type": 1. What is that, are there other types?

4) I assume that "mask" and "amount" are `x` and `a` in the Pedersen commitments as defined in the RingCT paper: `C(x,a) = xG + aH`. Is that correct? (Edit: as noted by Luigi in the comments, "mask" and "amount" are not `x` and `a` themselves which are kept secret on the blockchain, but are encrypted as `x'=x+s1` and `a'=a+s2` where `s1=Hs(d), s2=Hs(s1)` and `d` is the shared secret `rA=aR` between the sender and receiver.)

5) Why is there a field called "rctsig_prunable"? Is that some information that can be discarded later?

6) What are the fields "asig", "Ci", "MGs" and "ss"?

```
Found in blockchain at height 817804
020001020005878c01c451a40.....................f910db10c69e3ff616df1e8cd73403
{
  "version": 2, 
  "unlock_time": 0, 
  "vin": [ {
      "key": {
        "amount": 0, 
        "key_offsets": [ 17927, 10436, 804, 32, 3817
        ], 
        "k_image": "67e33ecb9fc4e697248ef57ca88aa626fe670ce1551598f9cbc1565089d43c41"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "vout": [ {
      "amount": 0, 
      "target": {
        "key": "7787bbef1a35b936e439aee4ae97cc245ba55ef35186efa3e9e86076a8fba1a6"
      }
    }, {
      "amount": 0, 
      "target": {
        "key": "f981817b20f7a866abb6a9cb29e8062a16fb15f11f0a20c0f0f296eb26e1eab1"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "extra": [ 1, 243, 27, 110, 49, 81, 52, 210, 213, 88, 152, 180, 126, 8, 156, 71, 33, 198, 169, 160, 109, 195, 45, 169, 137, 191, 32, 88, 36, 226, 210, 123, 115
  ], 
  "rct_signatures": {
    "type": 1, 
    "txnFee": 26000000000, 
    "ecdhInfo": [ {
        "mask": "d073ccb38b7e2d0e4cf0cf0ec80189bfd185e78452ae71bff7560cb80da4130e", 
        "amount": "927c6a073deb6030af17876b0e2f2a792e41ad7f8ee2b4f3200bd111818e6e0a"
      }, {
        "mask": "405c21e87c0a34452d4556617cc418820324de2dfaf3db962152ae3d37f80508", 
        "amount": "525f724a967c25be5e85292b8d822ab66e2c256af6861e758ebb500e16c9ad04"
      }], 
    "outPk": [ "e356a3285a7120d060df871a4a76d0f72550b1c323aa52252001dbff2d5a2fb2", "ca0d7844b052f6183a933dcf97a8a72acd5236d8a7f3c0b93631d5841752b504"]
  }, 
  "rctsig_prunable": {
    "rangeSigs": [ {
        "asig": "93942a5f22136543...................9b5e651c331a5f1960f", 
        "Ci": "4f08d0a8914f450723685e67....37c77d72f065bbc33157eec194be7a198bb"
      }, {
        "asig": "823405363e57560b334e2........95c9e9c9bc3726d57b4bad29a5d181bc02", 
        "Ci": "c3f62d192372296f50e916cbeef8....7b56e9962e1a660c68fed15d15c8af3"
      }], 
    "MGs": [ , 
      "ss": [ [ "f36300cd00b463281e31f32f942583800cbbe575028f0edee2a930b3aabbab08", "0acdd75b007bf52f7f7c1747450de2d99fd1a2e31c31fe6924c80bf563572f0a", ], [ "7d4c0e75b5d8aac314a8b8c5d4e54a8f2970bb92c51bdb2bbb1345ad21e3120f""2e8468a158ecf425af93c1db08f9e57be3e85fa1d33f56cef9266ad80b807d0d"], [ "19145dc851c8d79b89cc7eff289c03c583648d467a72143879db13178f5fcf05""4a0465facf45c36e89c7cac6afa0802a43e1fbd772ad7c4df821d45ef3a06c04"], [ "bbc090171e4620f7388f21e5335bff996eebcd22ac8a1b78e0e5dfe00b42600a", "d7e6ba126a9261cb33fa91deb7c179f9a0dc72b3096bc665ed8b06807b913c03", ], [ "4e5910093744557a3db315c8bc00d3422675c37fdbad4ded51ec86e8fa448c00", "b3ef06ad3142baef326ad6e70fda5e6316bb333f6519a9d893009a1d26eb5f05", ]]"c4ed83aef2fa07495da00ecdfecfc585c7f910db10c69e3ff616df1e8cd73403"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Key offsets are the set of outputs your ring is using as "fake"outputs, as well as yours. Outputs of a given denomination are ordered in blockchain order, and thus can be represented by their index in that list. This is smaller than using the public key. Moreover, they're stored as offsets from the previous one (the first one from 0), as this will result in smaller values, which can often result in a yet smaller amount of data, since those numbers are written out in a variable length output (kinda like UTF-8 in rough outline).

Extra is a grab bag of metadata. Typically, it will include the public key R for that transaction's one time key. It can also include an "extra nonce", which is used for the payment id, if the transaction has one. There are other things that can be put in there, including user defined data if so wanted.

Type 1 for ringct signatures is a particular way of laying the signatures. Type 1 and 2 exist. Type 1 is the original algorithm, and only works if all the real inputs are at the same index in all rings in that transaction. Obviously, it leaks information on the real inputs, so it's only used for single ring transactions, where this drawback does not matter, and it is slightly smaller than type 2. Type 0 means there are no signatures.

Mask and amount, I believe you are correct.

The rctsig_prunable field is the part of the RingCT signatures that can be pruned later, that's right. There is no pruning yet, just tidying up so that future pruning can be done with less changes.

I don't know the specifics for the remaining fields, but MGs are the MLSAGs, the overall signatures over the rest of the transaction and rct data.

Comment: Offsets: "Outputs of a given denomination are ordered in blockchain order". What does that mean for ringCT, since denominations will no longer be visible?// Is there a way (perhaps a daemon command) for me to query the blockchain with those numbers and have it return to me those outputs, their locations and amounts (if any) in the blockchain?// "they're stored as offsets from the previous one". Can you explain what you meant here?

Comment: Extra: In the example above, extra looks like a vector of numbers much like the key_offsets one. Can that be correct?// My guess would be that the transaction's one time key is under outPk. Is that also inside extra? Maybe I am having trouble understanding the JSON format.

Comment: RingCT outputs are members of one set, similar to pre-rct outputs being members of the set of outputs of that amount. No daemon command for this. Offsets from the previous means indices 3 5 8 9 become coded as 3 2 3 1, ie just the offsets. extra is dumped as a vector of bytes, yes. It contains the tx pub key. outPk contains the output public key for the corresponding output, and is not in extra.

Comment: @user141 for some inexplicable reason, extra has always been represented as an array of bytes while everything else is converted to hex. Every Cryptonote coin/clone is like this. I've suggested it be changed, but it hasn't been (yet).

Comment: There is a cn_deserialize tool which shows the internal structure of extra, though it appears to have been removed from git, so you'd have to get it from the history.

Comment: I think the reason for dumping extra as a bytestring is to allow user defined private data that other miners don't have to understand in order to process a transaction.

Comment: @user36303 That doesn't make any sense. It's simply a presentation thing. All other fields are presented to the user as hex characters. Extra is not. Unrecognized fields is orthogonal.

Comment: Additions: mask and amount are indeed x and a, but they are masked by shared secrets (otherwise everyone would know the amount!). "outPk" is not the output public key, that's in the prefix under "target"; "outPk" is the commitment C (it includes a duplicate of the target during construction for code purposes, that's why it's named like that). "asig" is ASNL from section 5.0.1. "ci" is a commitment to either 0 or i^2 for each i in 0,...,63. "ss" is the pair of "s"'s in MLSAGS as in the paper section 2.2. The untagged value at the end is the "c".

Comment: Ah, you want an array of bytes, still, but displayed as hex values, rather than decimal ? I thought the question was about an array of bytes as opposed to parsed data. Feel free to open a bug on github :)

Comment: @Luigi: I guess I should have written xG and aH, instead of x and a. Is that what you meant by "shared secrets"?// Thanks for clarifying that "asig" is ASNL. I went back to the paper and actually realized that I had been thinking that Monero was using Borromean signatures all along, and that might not be true. I am just reading on that now.// The only mention to "ss" I found in the paper is actually in section 5.1.1. Could that be what you meant? Or perhaps "ss" is an m-tuple in the paper, so here it is just a pair because m=2 outputs?// What do you mean by untagged value?

Comment: @Luigi: Thanks for the detailed reply! For some reason I didn't get the notification about your comment and only saw it today... I would love to see another of your Steemit posts on this whole topic.

Comment: @user141 My steemit posts have really fallen to the wayside unfortunately. I'll hopefully pick them back up soon. I have at least 2 more before getting to RingCT stuff though. By shared secrets I mean the sender computes a shared secret using the receiver's view key (similar to stealth addressing) and uses that to mask the amount and mask (with sc_add in this case). The paper doesn't have "ss"; it is used as the tag for the group of "s"'s (middle of page 6 of MRL-0005 "The signature is then given as..."). After the ss's, at the end of the MGs group, there is a single 32 byte value that is c.

Comment: @Luigi: I am not sure if I am missing something from your previous comments (I am still unpacking a few things), but I was noticing that I can't find the `R=rG` that is supposed to accompany the transaction (`r` as in `P=H(rA)G+B`). Do you know what field is that?

Comment: That goes into the pubkey field in tx_extra.

Comment: @user36303: I don't see a tx_extra field on the transaction above. I see only the "extra" field, but it looks like just a vector of small numbers, nothing like R. Do you see it in this transaction?

Comment: That's it. It's a list of chunks, as defined in tx_extra.h, one of which is the public key.