# Does /get_transaction return ring signatures or key image?

Tags: monerod, daemon, ring-signatures

i am trying to use https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_transactions To get the signatures.. But i was wondering if they are the correct data or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can return both. You just need to supply the parameter `"decode_as_json":true` in the request.

E.g.

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/get_transactions -d '{"txs_hashes":["a6eb34ec1893ce43630efc2f2dfa98cde2d5e7f37c18d1d8303f3a6436a4cc9f"],"decode_as_json":true}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' | jq .txs[0].as_json | jq -r .
```

Returns:

```
{
  "version": 2, 
  "unlock_time": 0, 
  "vin": [ {
      "key": {
        "amount": 0, 
        "key_offsets": [ 5164903, 2019770, 392759, 121787, 5621, 4659, 833, 1353, 6326, 487, 682
        ], 
        "k_image": "09ce24ca119516abe3097f7b17d9abd55f2b247eb2858db8e2806c6f62e170c8"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "vout": [ {
      "amount": 0, 
      "target": {
        "key": "1eb34205bb13a93464cad68e5222b45a0d68d7266bd9781577abab93e060cbd9"
      }
    }, {
      "amount": 0, 
      "target": {
        "key": "cf4615c23b707b98b867ccacc64eec88229cfefd5d327b9c0c6efdaecc907f09"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "extra": [ 2, 9, 1, 40, 48, 184, 10, 255, 26, 66, 138, 1, 108, 154, 91, 243, 197, 191, 163, 155, 52, 205, 239, 49, 230, 107, 38, 117, 24, 204, 4, 34, 138, 34, 8, 0, 207, 153, 25, 171, 39, 50, 132, 228
  ], 
  "rct_signatures": {
    "type": 3, 
    "txnFee": 65171565, 
    "ecdhInfo": [ {
        "mask": "df96ce17b64319e3bd0b7c4139fdcd1d9f657241951b980a3a8c5e741866ef06", 
        "amount": "1e6bb8747905c8cd8978f7e0cbc37ffb3768d4f4c192f67c433882619ef8d903"
      }, {
        "mask": "a5f7dcf90e8de4627f35906631c6499890dca104db804718a58d3f9061c4890a", 
        "amount": "3bd132ad121f6240c1f81992a3b8c82993af416c267f110aa74b99832256040b"
      }], 
    "outPk": [ "8095e9705336a50f8fa71d738e4e6e8d9cc4c121212f66cfe7e824a96c093d8b", "05917cd4ff34937bb27680359cac8482fb6fc77c9bad7e383a4f97e86ae8b7f8"]
  }, 
  "rctsig_prunable": {
    "nbp": 1, 
    "bp": [ {
        "A": "54864bfa9bf763fe962f1a3cb1ae7897abd5e1fd1541407619dab39ded2ba0c8", 
        "S": "9a9bf550d665b4c983d9ca1434a94ddf74cd3f93bb43cc5b312f9a1071b2e9c8", 
        "T1": "bd823f37a4c8b8873285aa10d10cf2c23d944da693bdb242f3774a2428b99409", 
        "T2": "715f8e5fd55650b5ef80e884c7d13c3bd162f8bb15bbccd337f0ec783d5de4ad", 
        "taux": "96c6021852b3c161174b98b1fa887fa9d6157b195aa2739fb669a5a06fb7440f", 
        "mu": "15a575cafb0f885321d150de5a16866c79eb95144a6d229eeed4c2028ad1df05", 
        "L": [ "2ca6824f645feb8f6ca51107332829ae838c5ce8dd88f64522639c48f95311fa", "ea00ee9d458052d54b55ae1898b8727dadbd4bf65087df4ba8ccd24d8bc9595c", "d77eca33674a151410a9ed9bb31c875b97e3c0d867ef43d95f8cac9fcbecfa75", "45b1974f41a6c95915b2497aa2acfa87e5fdd616b6ff19bcd404360e4c052a0d", "62e77f7288a5f1c6d0f4723e7e4f09e21657bd8a7eff81dfa75cbe395ad3faae", "260c92659d5cf1c2db9d91fdc79f435fb292b1a30d8c1c368e3bb5d96834e0b3", "8f6a35f35f0389295a0290083489b7c78d45d6c9c3e9019d64e06100a8d8a374"
        ], 
        "R": [ "f3c09d7cf1b7d5f6ed568516eb0457f6e694e71f2e9f5bedb685bd2edae59a9c", "41eee5b71d07315710d3ffc45150d6ddda9d1597fca8b73b9d0cb6cb93892fbb", "d334a4206fa66fde9b6e7ef7ecd9bd03ea047588f84be0d33229c998420a83f1", "dee7e3fa21ce5342c77cb43f8cb8dba2232de8b0bd9bb50673a4c974df3c9505", "08c49496964b837ad8179c7b01c640f9b46ce3a88c01a1048872e2f8824de9fc", "422dd9688b91ce4d81462d85fdf3f4b480bbdb34c61bc039c33d905c3a7a7570", "9fdf3f8d32797780d55391516155823204f5c4300d868df4b5f98a50e19723bf"
        ], 
        "a": "84643248d89d02585d012e32cce0a709754d0ed40d8ab023990e645187ae9e00", 
        "b": "858b587e5b43e58a5b4ecd769fbd1a3e2b708e980fe1a50fb653cf7747bd3b06", 
        "t": "ce35ce4c46061cb8feb6a79b9356f3e318241e163b1f0a3bc427cb0937d4790a"
      }
    ], 
    "MGs": [ {
        "ss": [ [ "907971dabfad683b422aca76233420f3e7cbeea347686727928223253b9e3208", "298c84744e1776effe4baf984f0174d7af9676028033e4f4bf9a028179a39b04"], [ "5cfd506c28d689edc5627828e7117487c80b44d1ba11773b854646c58389240b", "d85b408c34048c0fa4974cbf328992931bc03da492fd156d651c697a97b8f008"], [ "0469e2f91337d0edeceb73d11a36419d8fc7ece9251697d71921d1669565ae02", "365dce4c987e6559824ec6db3cb7f76e0264b136958e94f44adcfc6fc602c504"], [ "a0bac1275744ae611c627e06c5e69a431fe6d923752e8809133e9508c368ac03", "e6f027acb2b27eff5e3613206778b68c7120406822006a59a02663918a46b50f"], [ "f991f283e3329317d0dac18be7fcd0acb2ad05a93a858d176d8d5c60e7c4a606", "3e1ae8440ceebe89dcdfc9153b9a875b8462d0acaf20444bf05b39017473ec04"], [ "9298594c32e765ce223784796bf6d2920a22955e89dbe943086fb96418c37302", "321e0f5835312398ef0c55f31dbcfaaa16d29235e9da6dd9812a97eef05ecb09"], [ "bf274649eb4e92527c3866c020a8dc92a74e19de4562cfa1d392c5784dd4ff06", "6176aa153dcb0f8f03bb9f22d34371e38e3c36b318cf3d3ca45f43c5cc197a0f"], [ "20818cb604d3e370f82600f6e5c05d0058971bba066bd617ccfb22a9f9789c03", "23d391a9405b248b6496700d8235ec57a678c8989f69e77dc99bdd576737f308"], [ "daf34aaea3b741b50c174433c45e0748e1e8782e8df4bd7e4e325ac82de00306", "a707e00f532347c87b215b5d3fbd05289ba13b2f883fe0c57dc884b2164e020c"], [ "f9fed9fbdbc3aa7ddd839685fd4ad35bfb265403c34486ee81579b2a5eeec705", "6e9e6e3ef609015ac08c6c06794ee5be6e740a9b7591bf6a6c98646def61280b"], [ "4d7f2b6d22a65747171160b6ec33d027d08407b0ea72397dac94921afc99a003", "dfaad018892230122c3603224ca852a1beca0f1fe9b5ed6e5be52732624c9e0c"]], 
        "cc": "f3040844bf1f4d9c3329bcb898ad68db7f43ec35c69126aa0cd70492612a7e06"
      }], 
    "pseudoOuts": [ "c972e9efaf77c93fa5a54c4cde1513fd822679ab54eb8b04522f941a0888f5c9"]
  }
}
```

Comment: what are the ring signatures here?

Comment: `rct_signatures` and `rctsig_prunable`

Comment: https://xmrchain.net/search?value=a6eb34ec1893ce43630efc2f2dfa98cde2d5e7f37c18d1d8303f3a6436a4cc9f

if you see that there you can see that there are ring members but they are not shown anywhere in your json response return?

Comment: Your question was for how to get signatures and key images, not how to decode the ring members.

Comment: the once that is given in the ringsignatures is the encoded.. Could you tell me how do i decode that you the relevant signatures? that would be of great help.. thanks in advance

Comment: The ring members cannot be decoded from the ring signatures. They are specified in the `key_offsets` field. See https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/7576/rpc-method-to-translate-key-offsets

Comment: So how does the https://xmrchain.net/ gives us the detailed information about the ring members.. because when i click more details it shows me the signatures i obtained from get transaction only .. I am really confused.. can you please help me?

Comment: It looks them up per my last comment.

Comment: You have to understand firstly the difference between ring members and ring signatures. Next you need to understand that multiples methods may need calling depending on what information you are looking for. This answer should be marked as answered for this question as it explains how to get the ring signatures. Your [newer question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10586/api-call-for-ring-members) I have also just answered which details how to get at further information on the ring members. Depending on what information you are after, you may need further calls.