# API call for ring members

Tags: monerod, monero-wallet-cli, daemon, rpc

Is there any way that we can do an API call to the Monero daemon RPC to get all the ring members for a given transaction hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling `get_transactions`, you will have a list of the ring members in the `vin.key_offsets` field. You can then lookup these outputs using a call to `get_outs`.

An example of both calls:

`curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/get_transactions -d '{"txs_hashes":["a6eb34ec1893ce43630efc2f2dfa98cde2d5e7f37c18d1d8303f3a6436a4cc9f"],"decode_as_json":true}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json`

Returns `5164903, 2019770, 392759, 121787, 5621, 4659, 833, 1353, 6326, 487, 682` as the key_offsets (the ring members).

Each output after the first is incremented by the sum of the previous indexes. So the first member is at index `5164903`, the 2nd at `7184673` and so on.

So translated, these outputs are then:

`5164903, 7184673, 7577432, 7699219, 7704840, 7709499, 7710332, 7711685, 7718011, 7718498, 7719180`

To get further information on each ring member, you can then call `get_outs` like following (which gets the first and last):

`curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:18081/get_outs -d '{"get_txid":true,"outputs":[{"index":5164903},{"index":7719180}]}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Which returns:

```
{
  "outs": [{
    "height": 1545783,
    "key": "6dcc42839619ea4e1b1cb1b28d45659916207a445ec00e06ece45a7b7bfc1264",
    "mask": "449ce062721cbde5f282eeb292eb27636539b29c81a396fddeede73c72d0a66e",
    "txid": "124f70eb30ace64d577d82f193e0057b07fc4bdb053bf228dfc00b4e1099b1f1",
    "unlocked": true
  },{
    "height": 1694891,
    "key": "1089839b83fd45f7ab87a64398aad45176be4e6ee44872cf37c544358904d61c",
    "mask": "3f22409779524a01dc998e58fbccb58a02ca37e6e6be784f11d7b67dbdaf87e3",
    "txid": "4b1580e241b5499dd19faebc6c3c2dbf9bbb8a6c8144f538863fb3e71db10bd1",
    "unlocked": true
  }],
  "status": "OK",
  "untrusted": false
}
```

Comment: if there are different key_offset fields.. so do we still add it up?

Comment: If there was another vin in the tx (thus with it's own key_offsets field), it get's calculated/transformed in the same way - there is no relation to any other vin.key_offsets in the tx - each set of key_offsets is independent. Each offset in the set is the sum of the previous offsets in the set.

Comment: I was looking at some returns. And i see that there are some values that there are same key_offsets in the same transaction. EX- [272], [272]. Does that they are same ring members?

Comment: Calculation is as I described. Give me a tx id and I can show you the translation.

Comment: Tx - 9ecdadf8b95aa0a7b754559f5fd7a9bb0f5014c4107b3dc6b3331430b5ea984d
And
Tx- 405d367f7076cb39cae4f37067f4e716e77fbce62556d5d49487e41568e7cead

Comment: Firstly those are both _very_ old transactions (pre-RingCT), however, calculation is still as I described. [272] translates to 272. The fact there are _two_ vins each with separate key_offsets with [272], they are referring to the same output (which happen to be in a block with only a coinbase tx - block 00000273).

Comment: what was the block height from which RingCT was implemented?

Comment: Block height 1220517

Comment: cool thats a lot!!