# How can I get real inputs from key_offsets?

Tags: transaction-data, ring-signatures

As I get key_offsets from command "print_tx ... +json", how can I get the real inputs with those numbers?

For example, using command below..

`print_tx b43a7ac21e1b60ad748ec905d6e03cf3165e5d8c9e1c61c263d328118c42eaa6 +json`

we can get

```
"vin": [ {
  "key": {
    "amount": 0, 
    "key_offsets": [ 799048, 782511, 1197717, 216704, 841722
    ], 
    "k_image": "595a612d0df27181c46a8af70a9bd682f2a000124b873ba5d2b9f4b4e4efd672"
  }
 }
]
```

I think numbers 799048, 782511, 1197717, 216704, 841722 represent the outputs below:

```
   fbedf13299d8d923f66091443fafc3e10581ae5ca4630da1ef2f18284bb047cd
   80a2db336b5be228f60268b76c84632bfab69cf8c7c1a8cfdc907b49eb9ef3d3
   3cf5c769ceeb1b3dc17b978e93661ea917fa6b49e4ae2a70ad1ec24f1ebc7774
   94a371a5dbdf71b94ae366f21692a4b83534d68b9b74fa071b5877393ce59cca
   256bc1e1a19d05e6ebe2b388c330c0e76bf3a6961d563920e06ff5990b94c6da
```

My question is how can I get these public keys with those numbers.
Please help to give advice. Many thanks!

Comment: Actually, I'd like to know the mechanism of translating from offsets to outputs. However I still can not figure out from that Question.

Comment: There are multiple Q/As that explain, including the duplicate. Also: https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/10587/7493