# Understanding MLSAG in Monero transaction

Tags: ringct, cryptography, ring-signatures, key-image

This is a followup question to [Understanding the structure of Monero transaction](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/understanding-the-structure-of-a-monero-transaction) with emphasis on the MLSAG part.

Here's the transaction's structure again given with `print_tx 3cf34714d411d051722ec32990bf46567c7ae3432871f75f58005cb6b5b3021e`:

```
Found in blockchain at height 817804
020001020005878c01c451a40.....................f910db10c69e3ff616df1e8cd73403
{
  "version": 2, 
  "unlock_time": 0, 
  "vin": [ {
      "key": {
        "amount": 0, 
        "key_offsets": [ 17927, 10436, 804, 32, 3817
        ], 
        "k_image": "67e33ecb9fc4e697248ef57ca88aa626fe670ce1551598f9cbc1565089d43c41"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "vout": [ {
      "amount": 0, 
      "target": {
        "key": "7787bbef1a35b936e439aee4ae97cc245ba55ef35186efa3e9e86076a8fba1a6"
      }
    }, {
      "amount": 0, 
      "target": {
        "key": "f981817b20f7a866abb6a9cb29e8062a16fb15f11f0a20c0f0f296eb26e1eab1"
      }
    }
  ], 
  "extra": [ 1, 243, 27, 110, 49, 81, 52, 210, 213, 88, 152, 180, 126, 8, 156, 71, 33, 198, 169, 160, 109, 195, 45, 169, 137, 191, 32, 88, 36, 226, 210, 123, 115
  ], 
  "rct_signatures": {
    "type": 1, 
    "txnFee": 26000000000, 
    "ecdhInfo": [ {
        "mask": "d073ccb38b7e2d0e4cf0cf0ec80189bfd185e78452ae71bff7560cb80da4130e", 
        "amount": "927c6a073deb6030af17876b0e2f2a792e41ad7f8ee2b4f3200bd111818e6e0a"
      }, {
        "mask": "405c21e87c0a34452d4556617cc418820324de2dfaf3db962152ae3d37f80508", 
        "amount": "525f724a967c25be5e85292b8d822ab66e2c256af6861e758ebb500e16c9ad04"
      }], 
    "outPk": [ "e356a3285a7120d060df871a4a76d0f72550b1c323aa52252001dbff2d5a2fb2", "ca0d7844b052f6183a933dcf97a8a72acd5236d8a7f3c0b93631d5841752b504"]
  }, 
  "rctsig_prunable": {
    "rangeSigs": [ {
        "asig": "93942a5f22136543...................9b5e651c331a5f1960f", 
        "Ci": "4f08d0a8914f450723685e67....37c77d72f065bbc33157eec194be7a198bb"
      }, {
        "asig": "823405363e57560b334e2........95c9e9c9bc3726d57b4bad29a5d181bc02", 
        "Ci": "c3f62d192372296f50e916cbeef8....7b56e9962e1a660c68fed15d15c8af3"
      }], 
    "MGs": [ , 
      "ss": [ [ "f36300cd00b463281e31f32f942583800cbbe575028f0edee2a930b3aabbab08", "0acdd75b007bf52f7f7c1747450de2d99fd1a2e31c31fe6924c80bf563572f0a", ], [ "7d4c0e75b5d8aac314a8b8c5d4e54a8f2970bb92c51bdb2bbb1345ad21e3120f""2e8468a158ecf425af93c1db08f9e57be3e85fa1d33f56cef9266ad80b807d0d"], [ "19145dc851c8d79b89cc7eff289c03c583648d467a72143879db13178f5fcf05""4a0465facf45c36e89c7cac6afa0802a43e1fbd772ad7c4df821d45ef3a06c04"], [ "bbc090171e4620f7388f21e5335bff996eebcd22ac8a1b78e0e5dfe00b42600a", "d7e6ba126a9261cb33fa91deb7c179f9a0dc72b3096bc665ed8b06807b913c03", ], [ "4e5910093744557a3db315c8bc00d3422675c37fdbad4ded51ec86e8fa448c00", "b3ef06ad3142baef326ad6e70fda5e6316bb333f6519a9d893009a1d26eb5f05", ]]"c4ed83aef2fa07495da00ecdfecfc585c7f910db10c69e3ff616df1e8cd73403"]
  }
}
```

Now, I see `ss` as a 2X5 matrix of s values according to [RingCT paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1098.pdf), page 11 in the middle, "The signature is then given as...".
Questions:
 1. What is the actual structure in this case of `R` (the matrix to sign on)?
My understanding is that it's a matrix of 5 rows, each row j of the form:
${P_j, P_j + C_j - \sum_{i} C_{i,out}}$
 2. Don't we need 2 private keys (`x` and `x+z` as detailed in section 4 of the paper)? In that case, to fit the MLSAG scheme, don't we need another linkability tag in addition to the single key image (i.e., `I_2`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 11 in that paper is still only concerned with the general ring signature case, not particularly focused on the Pedersen Commitment part.

The `MGs` field corresponds to the struct `mgSig` in src/ringct/rctTypes.h:

```
typedef std::vector<key> keyV; //vector of keys
typedef std::vector<keyV> keyM; //matrix of keys (indexed by column first)
struct mgSig {
    keyM ss;
    key cc;
    keyV II;
};
```

In this case, `ss` is a matrix of 2 rows and 5 columns, and two entries in each `j`-th column are `(P_j, C_j - \sum_{i} C_{i,out})`. `II` corresponds to the key images.

To answer your question 2., yes, we do need two secret keys `x` and `z`, for the output public key `P_s = x*G` and its corresponding commitment part `C_s - \sum_{i} C_{i,out} = z*G`, respectively. We don't need the second key image corresponding to `z`, because the output public key `P` and its commitment `C` are always coupled, so double spend checking using just one key image suffices.

Comment: Regarding question 2: I understand that we do not need another key image for Link, but as far as I understand from MLSAG description section 2.2 ("The signature is then given as..."), we still need (I_1, ..., I_m) for the Verification part (in order to compute R_j for each j)

Comment: Those (I_1, ..., I_m) are key images, and of course are needed to prevent double spends. In the above example with a single input (m=1), the key image is `I=x*Hp(x*G)`. I interpreted your question as whether one also needs to use another one `J=z*Hp(z*G)` corresponding to the commitment part, and the answer is no.

Comment: Yes, you interpreted the question perfectly, I ask whether one needs to use another one `J=z*Hp(z*G)`.
Can you explain why the answer is no? it seems vital to be able to calculate the R_j's in the MLSAG scheme.

Comment: R is needed only for checking double spends. Double spend checking is already done using the first one `I=x*Hp(x*G)`, so there's no point in doing it again with `J=z*Hp(z*G)` because the secret keys `x` and `z` are *always* coupled; i.e. they're never used separately.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still missing something.
The LSAG "Veirfy" algorithm explicitly says: "An observer computes Li
, Ri, and ci for all i and checks that cn+1 = c1. Then the verifier checks that ci+1 = h (m, Li, Ri)
for all i mod n".
So - he must calculate Ri for each i, which needs the tag `I`, in order to verify the validity of the transaction.

Comment: You simply do not need to think about `R` for the second key `z`. Or put it differently, the verification algorithm looks like: `c_{i+1} = Hs(m, L_i, R_i, S_i)` where `L_i = c_i*P_i + r_i*G;    R_i = c_i*I + r_i*Hp(P_i);    S_i = c_i*Q_i + s_i*G` and `Q_i = C_i - \sum_j C_{j,out}`. Here, `S_i` is the equivalent of `L_i` but for the commitment part, with the secret key being `z`. This detail is not well explained in the paper. Directly looking into the source code src/ringct/rctSigs.cpp would probably be the most reliable way to check the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

A detailed breakdown of the various components of a Monero Transaction can be found in section 5 of [ringCT](https://delfr.com/crypto/ringct-moneros-building-blocks-part-9/) (or [pdf](https://delfr.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Monero_Building_Blocks_Part9.pdf) version if you prefer). It includes an explanation of the **"rct_signatures"** and **"MGs"** fields.
To better appreciate it though, it is recommended to understand the logic and modus operandi of MLSAGs and Confidential Transactions. This should help you out: [MLSAG](https://delfr.com/crypto/mlsag-signature-moneros-part-7/) (or [pdf](https://delfr.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Monero_Building_Blocks_Part7.pdf) version) and [CT](https://delfr.com/crypto/confidential-transaction-moneros-part-8/) (or [pdf](https://delfr.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Monero_Building_Blocks_Part8.pdf) version)

Comment: Thanks for answering.
If you see, I have references to that same paper in the question itself.
I have an issue with some specifics in this scheme implementation in Monero.

Comment: Please answer the question instead of just linking to external papers